# How do I create a trigger for the tables created in procedure find it below? You'll find there the sentences for trigger, too

Tags: function, datetime, triggers, varchar

```
create procedure init()
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_Stanging;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Visits;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Offices;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Patiens;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medics;

CREATE TABLE Medics(
Name varchar(50),
Surname varchar(50),
Type VARCHAR(50),
Speciality varchar(50))
engine InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Patiens(
Name varchar(50),
Surname varchar(50))
ENGINE InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Offices(
Name varchar(50))
ENGINE InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Visits(DateHour datetime,
Medics INT NOT NULL,
Patiens INT NOT NULL,
Offices INT NOT NULL)
ENGINE InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Table_Stanging(
DateVisit VARCHAR(50),
HourVisit TIME,
PatientName varchar(50),
PacientSurname varchar(50),
MedicName varchar(50),
MedicSurname varchar(50),
Office varchar(50));

ALTER TABLE Medics ADD unique(Name, Surname);

ALTER TABLE Patients ADD UNIQUE(Name,Surname);

ALTER TABLE Offices ADD UNIQUE(Name); 

ALTER TABLE Medics ADD COLUMN IDMed INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE Patients add COLUMN IDPat INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE Offices add COLUMN IDOff INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE Visits ADD COLUMN IDVis INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE Visits add constraint fk_Medics foreign key(Medics)
```

REFERENCES Medics(IDMed);

```
ALTER TABLE Visits add constraint fk_Patients foreign key(Patients)
```

REFERENCES Patients(IDPat);

```
ALTER TABLE Visits add constraint fk_Offices foreign key(Offices)
```

REFERENCES Offices(IDOff);

```
END$
```

The sentences are : the main populating tables - visits, patients and        offices - is done automatically using a trigger, importing data into the staging  table. The trigger attached staging table runs automatically when you insert new records and performs the following operations: - calls a function that formats the correct date (carefully! Column on the staging table must be defined as varchar, otherwise NEW.data will be 0000-00- 00!). It receives as argument two strings (time and date in the format in which they appear in the file, example: 22/04/2005,01:52:34,) and returns a value of type DATETIME representing the date + time of the visit as it should appear in the table Visits; 
-add appropriate records patients in tables and cabinets, causing foreign key value in the table Visits using LAST_INSERT_ID () or add SELECT;
- Visits table following procedures using the previously calculated values.

Comment: Please don't add formalities to the title and end of the question. It would also be helpful if you broke your question down into paragraphs for easier reading.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a little bit off the standards. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and edit your question so it becomes easier for people to answer it.

Comment: I understand, but can you help me by creating a trigger using the tables that I've created inside the procedure 'init' with the sentences written after it? I don't know how to do. Please help me. Thank you.